# Why would Android Studio 1.0 rc start downloading Android SDK without detecting if there existing one?

Tags: android, sdk

I've installed Android Studio 1.0 rc and Android SDK in my Archlinux box. But when I try to create a new Android Application, the AS would try to download another set of SDK directly from dl-ssl.google.com. I mean why, why wouldn't it start first and let me configure the SDK path? (I am in mainland China, so the connect will be reset all the times, in another word, AS will not start to workspace.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like that is in the known issues list: http://tools.android.com/knownissues

> A bug in Android Studio 1.0 RC1 causes the Setup Wizard to show up and ask you to install an SDK on each startup. To work around this, you can edit the idea.properties file in the bin folder such that it has the below line as well:

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

> PLEASE NOTE: This will break patch updating to the next version. We now check full binary checksums on the whole installation to prevent various install corruption bugs as well as to preserve application signatures. Therefore, make a copy of this file first, and before updating, put it back. (Alternatively, just download the full image of RC2 when it is released.)

Comment: Thanks, I just don't know how to describe this question. By the way, thanks for let me know [tools.android.com](https://tools.android.com).

Comment: RC2 is out now, I presume this issue is fixed there

Comment: I have been struggling with this for ages and google could not provide useful links. Now am in. Migrating from Eclipse to android studio.