# Android Studio stuck on loading during the startup

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have weird problem - Android Studio is stuck on loading.

I tried to reinstall it - the same result.

I tried to relaunch - the same result.

[image]

Comment: May be internet connectivity problem, have you check internet connectivity ?

Comment: Did you add any new library in build.gradle?

Comment: Check your `Firewall` please

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure you have disconnected your android phone from your computer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem a few days ago.

> That is the solution:

1. Open file Android Studio setup directory/bin/idea.properties
2. Add `disable.android.first.run=true` to tail,
   or `-Ddisable.android.first.run=true` on recent canaries
3. Restart AS

Hope that it's useful for you.

Comment: More detail on this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085806/why-would-android-studio-1-0-rc-start-downloading-android-sdk-without-detecting

Answer (score 0):

type "flutter clean" in terminal. works for me